# Fast extraction of rows in R

Tags: r, performance, matrix, combinations, extract

I have many binary matrices from which I want to extract every possible combination of three rows into a list. I then want to sum the columns of each of the extracted row combinations.

My current method is below, but it is extremely slow.

```
set.seed(123)
x <-  matrix(sample(0:1, 110 * 609, replace = TRUE), 110, 609)
row.combinations <- t(combn(nrow(x),3))
extracted.row.combns <- lapply(1:nrow(row.combinations), FUN = function(y) x[c(row.combinations[y,1],row.combinations[y,2],row.combinations[y,3]),])
summed.rows <- lapply(extracted.row.combns, colSums)
```

How could this be sped up?

Answer (score 4):

Using `?combn` and an inline function as an argument, I can run this analysis in under 5 seconds on my current machine:

```
combn(nrow(x), 3, FUN=function(r) colSums(x[r,]), simplify=FALSE)
```

Comment: @ZheyuanLi - admittedly I have a reasonably beefy machine over here :-) 15 seconds for 216K extractions is reasonably quick though.

Comment: This seems to be slower on my machine. 
`library(microbenchmark)`

`microbenchmark(
  extracted.row.combns <- lapply(1:nrow(row.combinations), FUN = function(y) x[c(row.combinations[y,1],row.combinations[y,2],row.combinations[y,3]),]),
  summed.rows <- lapply(extracted.row.combns, colSums)
) # total = 4.13 ms`

`microbenchmark(summed.rows <- combn(nrow(x), 3, FUN=function(r) colSums(x[r,]), simplify=FALSE)) # total = 5.43 ms`

Comment: @SNSBMS1 - 5.43ms? That doesn't sound right. Also, your benchmark totally excludes your `combn` call and jumps straight to the second line.

Comment: Oops, my bad.
`microbenchmark(
  row.combinations <- t(combn(nrow(x),3)),
  extracted.row.combns <- lapply(1:nrow(row.combinations), FUN = function(y) x[c(row.combinations[y,1],row.combinations[y,2],row.combinations[y,3]),]),
  summed.rows <- lapply(extracted.row.combns, colSums),
  unit = "s"
) # total = 7.3 s`

`microbenchmark(summed.rows <- combn(nrow(x), 3, FUN=function(r) colSums(x[r,]), simplify=FALSE), unit = "s") # total = 5.34s`

Answer (score 1):

We can make this faster with `combnPrim` from [gRbase](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gRbase/index.html).

```
library(gRbase)
lapply(combnPrim(nrow(x), 3, simplify = FALSE), function(r) colSums(x[r,]))
```

#### Benchmarks

```
system.time(x1 <- combn(nrow(x), 3, FUN=function(r) colSums(x[r,]), simplify=FALSE))
#  user  system elapsed 
#  6.46    0.21    6.67 

system.time(x2 <- lapply(combnPrim(nrow(x), 3, simplify = FALSE), 
                     function(r) colSums(x[r,])))
# user  system elapsed 
#  4.61    0.22    4.83
```

Comment: Not heard of this package - useful! Though even this becomes super slow on bigger matrices e.g. `matrix(sample(0:1, 609 * 110, replace = TRUE), 609, 110)`

Comment: @SNSBMS1  In the one example you posted, it is more efficient than `combn`